# How to reduce compilation time and which cases will this code fail

Tags: java, arrays, loops, time

Problem-
Monk loves to preform different operations on arrays, and so being the principal of Hackerearth School, he assigned a task to his new student Mishki. Mishki will be provided with an integer array A of size N and an integer K , where she needs to rotate the array in the right direction by K steps and then print the resultant array. As she is new to the school, please help her to complete the task.
Input:
The first line will consists of one integer T denoting the number of test cases.
For each test case:

1. The first line consists of two integers N and K, N being the number of elements in the array and K denotes the number of steps of rotation.
2. The next line consists of N space separated integers , denoting the elements of the array A.
   It is failing a few test cases, I dont know which and also how to reduce time complexity.
   Here is my code I did all research I could do from my end. Also please give easy solutions as I am a beginner.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int k = sc.nextInt();
            int v[] = new int[n];

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                v[j] = sc.nextInt();
            }

            for (int m = 1; m <= k; m++) {
                int temp = v[n - 1];
                for (int p = 1; p < n; p++) {

                    v[n - p] = v[n - (p + 1)];

                }
                v[0] = temp;

            }
            for (int a : v) {
                System.out.print(a + " ");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try to create test cases and find which work and which fail.

Comment: I tried, all passed, couldn't find a case that failed this code also I think I followed homework guidelines and did all research I could do on this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not certain I understood the code but what you posted works as far as I can tell.

I refactored it all to make it easier to digest - better naming, lots of parts extracted to methods, removed the need for a scanner so I could run a bunch of my own test cases against the a "rotate" method to check inputs vs expected outputs.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Application {

    public void run(int testCases, int arraySize, int rotations, String[] arrayElements) {
        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            getRotatedArray(arraySize, rotations, arrayElements);
        }
    }

    public int[] getRotatedArray(int arraySize, int rotationXTimes, String[] arrayElements) {
        int[] a = new int[arraySize];
        populateIntArray(arrayElements, a);
        rotateArray(rotationXTimes, a);
        Arrays.toString(a);
        return a;
    }

    private void rotateArray(int rotations, int[] array) {
        for (int m = 1; m <= rotations; m++) {
            // get last item of array...
            int length = array.length;
            int temp = array[length - 1];
            // shift elements 1 position right
            for (int p = 1; p < length; p++) {
                array[length - p] = array[length - (p + 1)];
            }
            // first  element becomes last.
            array[0] = temp;
        }
    }

    private int[] populateIntArray(String[] arrayElements, int[] array) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayElements.length; j++) {
            array[j] = Integer.parseInt(arrayElements[j]);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Some tests:

```java
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ApplicationTest {

    private Application app;

    @Before
    public void setUp()  {
        app = new Application();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(0 , 0, new String[]{});

        assertEquals(0, result.length);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(1 , 0, new String[]{"0"});

        assertEquals(1, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(1 , 1, new String[]{"0"});

        assertEquals(1, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(1 , 2, new String[]{"0"});

        assertEquals(1, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(2 , 0, new String[]{"0","1"});

        assertEquals(2, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test6() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(2 , 1, new String[]{"0","1"});

        assertEquals(2, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1,0}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test7() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(2 , 2, new String[]{"0","1"});

        assertEquals(2, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test8() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(3 , 0, new String[]{"0","1","2"});

        assertEquals(3, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1,2}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test9() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(3 , 1, new String[]{"0","1","2"});

        assertEquals(3, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{2,0,1}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test10() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(3 , 2, new String[]{"0","1","2"});

        assertEquals(3, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1,2,0}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test11() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(3 , 3, new String[]{"0","1","2"});

        assertEquals(3, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1,2}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test12() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(4 , 0, new String[]{"0","1","2","3"});

        assertEquals(4, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1,2,3}, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test13() {
        int[] result = app.getRotatedArray(4 , 4, new String[]{"0","1","2","3"});

        assertEquals(4, result.length);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1,2,3}, result);
    }
}
```

All tests passed.

If you read the tests you should be able to see I'm providing some **input**, exercising a particular method (performing some **process**), and checking the **output** against what I expect it to be.

i.e. I'm testing the `getRotatedArray` works according to expectations. And it does.

When you say it breaks and you don't know where, I'd suggest adding some `System.out.println` statements so you can verify the application is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: hmm, I will work on that, appreciate that you did some research on the code.